# How to remove address , page no date from HTML Print

Tags: html, css

I am using the below code to print a specific part from a Page.

```
<!-- CSS for the things we want to print (print view) -->
<style type="text/css" media="print">

#SCREEN_VIEW_CONTAINER{
        display: none;
    }
.other_print_layout{
        background-color:#FFF;
    }
</style>



<div id="SCREEN_VIEW_CONTAINER">
 THIS PART WILL NOT BE PRINTED
</div>

<br /> <br />


<div id="PRINT_VIEW">
   THIS PART WILL BE PRINTED
</div>
```

Problem is still page no , web address date shows in the print . I want to remove these . Check the attached image . I want to remove yellow parts

[Want to remove yellow parts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atZuw.png)

Any idea ?

Comment: You cannot control the browser's print header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the print Dialogue :

More Settings ==> Untick **`Headers And Footers`**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm :P